# Problem with content - not loading

Tags: content

So, this is my problem... Everything in my wordpress website is up and running, except when I get into a post and the content simply doesn't load. Everything else does, except for the post content.

This happened when I was trying to install a content locker from incent.ly and I came up into a problem: I didn't know how to install different lockers into different posts, as the code had to be pasted before the  tag.

So.. I downloaded and installed a plugin called: "custom field template", apparently very known around the community, and what I did was:

- Insert the content locker code into a "template content" area and in the "Post-id" I put the id of the post I wanted to lock.

And bam, every post stopped working. Now, I've uninstalled the plugin and the problem remains. And I just don't know where to look for the problem.

I have ran the debug test on a post and, in the area where the content should be, this appeared:

> "Warning: `call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function '`add_post_content`' not found or invalid function
>   name in
>   `/var/www/vhosts/gentlefantasies.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php on
>   line 173`"

Answer (score 3):

The error message you get means that a function has been hooked without a valid callback.

In other words it means that somewhere in your theme or in a plugin a function has been set but it's not "hooked" properly. See the example :

```
function add_post_content()  //<- the callback
{
// blabla
}
add_action( 'hook_name', 'wrong_name_function' );//<- hooked in WP
```

So 'wrong_name_function' has to be replaced with 'add_post_content'.